# Why is UINavigationBar animating incorrectly when using large titled NavBar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

If I set the NavBar to default and translucent, then the animation is just like the AppStore animation.

[image: Settings for working animation in Xcode storyboard.]

Here is what it looks like with these settings.

[image: Correct Animation Gif]

Here is what it looks like with the non-default settings.

[image: Settings where animation jumps and moves incorrectly]

[image: Incorrect Animation Gif]

Here is my code for setting the NavBar to large title.

```java
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData()
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}
```

Here is an Apple Demo Project that I looked at to double check things. I was originally using a non-transparent background because I thought it looked better.

Apple Demo: [Customizing Your App's Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar)

I'd like to know if there is any way to set a gradient or a color and have the animation work correctly, and have the background of the NavBar not be transparent.